# How to enqueue JavaScript file that depends on CSS stylesheet

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-script, wp-register-style

I'm trying to set up a build process for JS/CSS assets to work with my WordPress theme.

In my JavaScript file, I can do this:

```js
// src/button.js
import React from 'react';
import './Button.css';
function Button(props) {
  return <Button>Click me</Button>;
}
```

The build process produces a handy JSON file:

```json
{
  "src/button.js": {
    "path": "build/button.js",
    "dependencies": [
      "src/button.css"
    ]
  },
  "src/button.css": {
    "path": "build/button.css",
    "dependencies": []
  }
}
```

I'd like to utilize this JSON structure to enqueue assets on demand with the correct dependencies. Ideally, something like:

```js
wp_enqueue_script('src/button.js', 'path/to/build/button.js', ['src/button.css']);
```

However, I couldn't find a combination of `wp_register_{script,style}` `wp_enqueue_{script,style}` that works, and I'm under the impression WordPress can't currently handle JS files that depend on CSS files via these methods.

Is that really the case? Is there an alternative way to enqueue the stylesheets necessary for a particular JavaScript file?

Comment: I don't think it's technically possible for a JavaScript script to actually "depend" on a CSS stylesheet, because neither language is capable of directly interacting with the other, short of manipulating rules in an already loaded stylesheet through DOM APIs. If you're not doing that, then I'm not sure what sort of dependent functionality you're thinking of here. Importing CSS (or something that compiles into CSS) into a JS source file is a bundling convention esoteric to certain build processes - it simply serves as a cue for the build tool to process the CSS.

Comment: E.g., we wouldn't tell WordPress that a stylesheet depends on a JS script because the stylesheet's going to function just fine if we don't also load the JS script, and vis-versa. Maybe not to the same effect as having both loaded, but for the simple functional requirement of loading the assets neither actually depends on the other.

Comment: I mostly mean it in the _JS that depends on CSS_ direction, to allow users to load a JavaScript widget with its associated styles. It's not a strict dependency, more of a "let's make sure this <link> is also added to the page" thing. Looking a bit through the WP code, it currently seems to be a limitation of WP_Scripts and WP_Styles being two separate buckets.

Comment: Ah I see yeah - in that case no direct means to link them within WordPress's systems, you are correct. The closest it might come to grouping assets into a "component" or "feature" is really just associating assets with a block in a `block.json` file. I don't reckon we'll see much beyond that, as I wouldn't think there'd be much of a benefit to the core systems. But it could definitely be a neat utility to drop into themes and plugins :) . "Feature-based" core systems which explicitly associate assets with their source extensions *would* be pretty nifty though...

Comment: Ah, thanks for the `block.json` tip, sounds like something I should dig into!

Comment: For sure! You might want to take a look at the [`@wordpress/create-block`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block/) and [`@wordpress/scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-scripts/) packages as well, if you haven't already - the latter is a encapsulated toolchain a la `react-scripts`, and the former scaffolds a plugin to add a custom block to the Block Editor. Might find some other nifty tricks in there which you might be able to integrate into your own build process.